# Correct preposition choice

Tags: prepositions

> 1) There is **a color tone difference** between the glass wall building and the prefabricated buildings.
>
> 2) There is **a difference in color tone** between the glass wall building and the prefabricated buildings.
>
> 3) There is **a difference of color tone**  between the glass wall building and the prefabricated buildings.

Which sentence is better than the others? Is there any grammatically wrong sentence or all of them correct or do sentences have different meaning ? I wonder if especially third one is correct or not.

Comment: 1 and 2 are natural. 3 less so

Answer (score 1):

The complexity here is that "tone" is a technical word when talking about colors.

https://blog.hubspot.com/marketing/color-theory-design

> Tone (or Saturation) You can also add both white and black to a color
>   to create a tone. Tone and saturation essentially mean the same thing,
>   but most people will use saturation if they're talking about colors
>   being created for digital images. Tone will be used more often for
>   painting.

Or visually, something like so.

[image]

But there is also the non-technical meaning of tone just meaning the colors are different.

So each of your sentences is grammatically acceptable. If interpreted non-technically, they are pretty much interchangeable. If interpreted technically, then 1) means there is a difference of one tone level. "A color tone" difference. 2) and 3) mean there is *some* difference without specifying how much.